# How do the definitions of *, / and % guarantee that a/b * b + a%b == a?

Tags: c++, algebra, modulo

This is true according to Straustrup in PPP, page 68.

Using algebra I can reduce it to

```
   a/b * b + a%b == a
     a     + a%b == a,  // b in numerator and denominator cancel each other
```

But that still doesn't explain the proof.

Comment: You can't reduce `a/b * b` to `a` in integer arithmetic. `3/2*2 == 1*2 == 2`.

Comment: Thank you @FrançoisAndrieux

Quick question: 

what is 2/3 in integer arithmetic?   Is it 0 or 1 ?
what is 2/2 in integer arithmetic?

Comment: @etonw First is 0, second is 1. Look up integer division

Answer (score 2):

For each two integers `a` and `b` you have equation

```
a = n * b + r;
```

where `n` is how many times `a` is divisible by `b` and `r` is a remainder.

For example if `a` is equal to `25` and `b` is equal to `6` then you can write

```
a = 4 * 6 + 1
    n   b   r
```

Using operators of C++ you can write the same like

```
a = a / b * b + a % b
      n           r
```

Answer (score 1):

You omitted the fact that `a` and `b` are integers.

Operator `/` with two integers will perform whole number division and discard remainder. The remainder can be calculated with operator `%`. 
In other words expression `a/b` says how many times `b` can fit in a as a whole. And `a%b` what would be left in `a` after performing that operation. The result of expression`a - (a % b)` would leave no remainder being divided by `b`. 
So `(a / b) * b` is equal to `a - (a % b)` which gives us following expression `(a / b) * b == a - (a % b)`

Comment: Thank your your time @teivaz ! I have decided to write a program and test the results to figure out this integer division rules

Comment: @etonw It's generally better to understand the theory first and test second. Relying on observed behavior can leave you with misconceptions. Worst, in c++, you may eventually be observing undefined behavior which can wreck havoc on your sanity and lead you to believe all sorts of incorrect things. Please carefully read this answer, it's accurate and simple.

Comment: Thank you @FrançoisAndrieux